# Lemonbar + Perl scripting for workspaces

Tags: performance, gui, perl, x11

I have made this program to simulate polybar's `bspwm` module. So far, it works flawlessly; however, it consumes too much RAM and CPU (16-30%). I suspect it is the `while` loop causing the trouble, but what can be done to reduce resource usage?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Switch;
use List::MoreUtils qw(first_index);

$SIG{INT}=sub{ die "goodnight !\n $!"; };
my $underline='#ffffff';
my $default_background='#51002f';
my $default_workspace_background='#727272';
my $default_workspace_foreground='#ffffff';
my $default_foreground='#ffffff';
my $focussed_background='#000000';
my $focussed_foreground='#ffffff';
my $occupied_background='#3a3a3a';
my $occupied_foreground='#ffffff';
my @desktops=qx/ bspc query -D /;
my @lemonbar_array=();
my $lemonbar_string="%{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground}%{+u}    0x00400004  %{-u}%{B-}%{F-}";
my $date_string="%{c}%{B$focussed_background}%{F$default_foreground}%{+u}   %date   %{-u}%{B-}%{F-}";

my $add_this="%{+u}%{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground} %{A:firefox:}  web  %{A}  %{B-}%{F-} %{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground} %{A:evince:}  pdf  %{A} %{B-}%{F-} %{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground} %{A:libreoffice:}  doc  %{A} %{B-}%{F-} %{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground} %{A:firefox youtube.com:}  youtube  %{A} %{B-}%{F-} %{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground} %{A:firefox netflix.com:}  netflix  %{A} %{B-}%{F-} %{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground} %{A:firefox gmail.com:}  gmail  %{A} %{B-}%{F-} %{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground} %{A:firefox protonmail.com:}  protonmail  %{A} %{B-}%{F-} %{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground} %{A:nautilus:}  files  %{A} %{B-}%{F-} %{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground} %{A:urxvt:}  terminal  %{A} %{B-}%{F-}%{-u}";

for(my $i=0;$i<=9;$i++){ 
    push(@lemonbar_array,$lemonbar_string); 
}

my $current_monitor='';

while() { 
    my $date=gmtime();
    $date_string=~s/%date/$date/;
    $current_monitor=qx/bspc query -D -d/;
    my $index_current_monitor=first_index { $_ eq $current_monitor } @desktops;
    my $index_print=$index_current_monitor+1;
    $lemonbar_array[$index_current_monitor]=~s/(?<=B)#.{6}/$focussed_background/;
    $lemonbar_array[$index_current_monitor]=~s/(?<=F)#.{6}/$focussed_foreground/;
    $lemonbar_array[$index_current_monitor]=~s/0x00.{6}/$index_print/;
    for(my $i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        if($desktops[$i] ne $current_monitor){
            my $i1=$i+1;
            $lemonbar_array[$i]=~s/0x00.{6}/$i1/;
            if(scalar(my @n=qx/bspc query -N -d $desktops[$i]/) gt 0){ 
                $lemonbar_array[$i]=~s/(?<=B)#\w{6}/$occupied_background/;
                $lemonbar_array[$i]=~s/(?<=F)#\w{6}/$occupied_foreground/;
                }
            else{
                $lemonbar_array[$i]=~s/(?<=B)#\w{6}/$default_workspace_background/;
                $lemonbar_array[$i]=~s/(?<=F)#\w{6}/$default_workspace_foreground/;



            }
        }
    }
    
    print "%{l}@lemonbar_array $date_string %{r}$add_this\n";
}
```

Comment: As for cpu, cut down number of shell calls per minute.

Answer (score 2):

### Overview

It is great that you:

- Used `strict` and `warnings`
- Leveraged other people's code by using the `List::MoreUtils` module
- Minimized namespace population by importing only needed functions
- Used meaningful names for variables

### Performance

It is wasteful to execute these lines inside the `while` loop:

```
my $date=gmtime;
$date_string=~s/%date/$date/;
```

The substitution only happens once during the first time though the loop.
That is when the literal `%date` string is replaced with the
return value of `gmtime`.  Every other time thorough the loop,
the match never occurs.

Before the loop, store the return value from `gmtime`, then interpolate it
directly into the `$date_string`, rather than doing a substitution with `s///`:

```
my $date = gmtime;
my $date_string = "%{c}%{B$focussed_background}%{F$default_foreground}%{+u}   $date   %{-u}%{B-}%{F-}";
```

### Unused code

Remove this line:

```
use Switch;
```

The module is not used, and it is notorious for causing problems.

### [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Since you execute this external command several times, store it in a variable:

```
 my $cmd = 'bspc query ';
```

### Be explicit

The `while` has an empty expression:

```
while()
```

Although it is documented that
this results in an infinite loop, it is not obvious when looking at the code.  It is clearer to use `1` as the expression:

```
while (1)
```

### Perlish

It is considered more "Perlish" to use `map` instead of the `for/push` combination for
simple code:

```
my @lemonbar_array=();
for(my $i=0;$i<=9;$i++){ 
    push(@lemonbar_array,$lemonbar_string); 
}
```

Consider this instead:

```
my @lemonbar_array = map { $lemonbar_string } 1 .. 10;
```

Also, instead of the C-style `for` loop:

```
for(my $i=0;$i<10;$i++){
```

Consider this instead:

```
for my $i (0 .. 9) {
```

### Long line

Long lines are hard to understand and maintain.  This should be broken up:

```
my $add_this="%{+u}%{B$default_background}%{F$default_foreground} %{A:firefox:}  ...
```

### Whitespace

Add a single space before and after these operators for better readability: `=` and `=~`.
[perltidy](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Tidy/view/bin/perltidy) can be used
to add consistent formatting to your code.

Delete the extra blank lines in the inner `for` loop.

```
        else{
            $lemonbar_array[$i]=~s/(?<=B)#\w{6}/$default_workspace_background/;
            $lemonbar_array[$i]=~s/(?<=F)#\w{6}/$default_workspace_foreground/;



        }
```

### Linting

[perlcritic](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/view/bin/perlcritic)
identifies some issues.

Trailing whitespace is unnecessary and can be annoying.  It should be removed.

Don't use parentheses with built-in functions like `gmtime`.

### Documentation

Consider adding some usage notes at the top of the file as
plain old documentation ([POD](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod)),
something as simple as:

```
=pod

Simulate polybar's bspwm module.

=cut
```